# Adding different information in a python linked list and printing it

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to add different information in a python linked list and printing it, but there seems to be an error. I want to print the ID, the Music and the artist name. This is my error. 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\DSAG\DSAG coding\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 101, in <module>
    for i in range (0,LinkedList.len_link()):
TypeError: len_link() missing 1 required positional argument: 'list'`

This is my code:

```
class Node :
  def __init__(self, newData=None, nextNode=None):
    self.data = newData
    self.next  = nextNode

  def getData(self):
    return self.data

def setData(self,newData):
    self.data = newData

  def getNext(self):
    return self.next

  def setNext(self,newNode):
    self.next = newNode

class music :
  def __init__(self, ID, musicname, artistname):
    self.ID = ID
    self.musicname = musicname
    self.artistname = artistname

  def printlist(self):
    print("ID : " + format(self.ID))
    print("Music : " + format(self.musicname))
    print("Artist : " + format(self.artistname))

class LinkedList :
  def __init__(self):
    self.head  = None
    self.size=0

  def next(self,newNode):
    self.head = newNode

  def len_link(list):
    temp=list.head
    count=0
    while(temp):
        count+=1
        temp=temp.next
    return count

  def printAll(self):

    node = None

    if self.head is not None:
        node = self.head
        print(node.getData())
        while(node.getNext() is not None):
            node = node.getNext()
            print(node.getData())

  def AddMusicToTheFront(self,data):
    if(self.head==None):
        newnode=Node(data)
        self.head=newnode
    else:
        current=self.head
        while(current.next!=None):
            current=current.next
        current.next=Node(data)
    self.size=self.size+1

  def AddMusicAtPosition (self, data, position):
    if(position==0):
        newnode=Node(data)
        newnode.next=self.head
        self.head=newnode

    elif(position>self.size):
        print("\nOut of Range\n")

    elif(position==self.size):
        self.AddMusicToTheFront(data)

    else:
        current=self.head
        count=0
        while(current!=None):
            if(count==position-2):
                break
            else:
                count+=1
                current=current.next
        newnode=Node(data)
        newnode.next=current.next
        current.next=newnode




list = LinkedList()
list.AddMusicToTheFront(music(1, "Lauv", "Chasing Fire"))
list.AddMusicToTheFront(music(2, "Panic! At The Disco", "High Hopes"))
list.AddMusicToTheFront(music(3, "Bishop Briggs", "River"))
list.AddMusicAtPosition(music(4,"Why Don't We", "Hooked"),2)

for i in range (0,LinkedList.len_link()):
    music.printlist()
```

This is my desired outcome :

```
ID:1
Artist : Lauv
Music : Chasing Fire
```

^This code will be the same for the rest of the information that I will include later

Comment: do not use `list` as a variable name or function parameter. take a look at your len_link function, it expects a list argument.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh okay i understand and i have change it but currently I have an error that points to `music.printlist()`

Comment: you may want to start a different question then.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to define `len_link` like this:

```
  def len_link(self):
    temp=self.head
    count=0
    while(temp):
        count+=1
        temp=temp.next
    return count
```

Then you can instantiate a LinkedList object (`ll=LinkedList()`) and then call `len_link()` like this `ll.len_link()`.

So your code would look like this:

```
ll = LinkedList()
ll.AddMusicToTheFront(music(1, "Lauv", "Chasing Fire"))
ll.AddMusicToTheFront(music(2, "Panic! At The Disco", "High Hopes"))
ll.AddMusicToTheFront(music(3, "Bishop Briggs", "River"))
ll.AddMusicAtPosition(music(4,"Why Don't We", "Hooked"),2)

for i in range (0,ll.len_link()):
    music.printlist()
```

Comment: okay i understand, but I have an error which points to the ( music.printlist() ). I am not too sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (0,LinkedList.len_link(list)): music.printlist()    #pass list in the len_link finction
```

And music is not set. it might get error because music never initiated and has no attributes, so when it'll try to print, error will occur.

what you need to do is extract an element fromt he list which is a music object then on that obj call `printlist()`

Comment: Im sorry, but im not too sure about the extracting of an element.